# Easy way to convert complex json to simple POJO files for Android

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2, pojo

I'm trying to convert complex json response to simple POJO objects. What I mean, I can convert this json response to pojo with ***www.jsonschema2pojo.org*** , but it generates me 47 files. I don't want this solution.

I want simple and light POJO objects. So, what I need, a few pojo files (May be max 5-6 files) with entire json attributes.

#### Example

My sample json response ( **Wordpress** ):
https://pastebin.ca/3855759

And the generator creates these files:
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npjWO.png)

I read these and similar posts but I could't fix my issue;

*stackoverflow.com/questions/41692991/convert-nested-json-to-simple-json*
*stackoverflow.com/questions/31117784/convert-complex-json-to-one-level-pojo-using-jackson*

So, do you have any solution to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try GSOnFormat plugin from in android studio plugins.
you can install it from file >Settings>plugins>browse repository>GSONFORMAT

use it using alt+insert

Comment: I tried but I don't have 15 reputation :) If you give me 5 rep I can up vote your answer :)